# Formatting numbers one zero less with D3 (e.g. 15 -> 1.5)

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, plotly

Plotly uses D3 for [formatting ticks](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#using-tickformat-attribute) so, I want the ticks of a plot to have one zero less.

My code:

```
# Spatial axes
dx, dz = 100, 100
x = np.arange(0, 60000, dx)
z = np.arange(0, 30000, dz)

[zz, xx]= np.meshgrid(z, x, indexing='ij')

# Velocity model
vel = 1000 + 0.032 * zz

fig = px.imshow(vel, labels=dict(x="x[km]", y="z[km]", color="Velocity (m/s)"), color_continuous_scale='RdBu')
fig.update_layout(title='Raytrace')
```

The result:
[image]

I need both axes ticks to have one zero less as my section dimensions are z=[0,30] km and x=[0,60] km. I know that if I change `dx` and `dz` to `1000` the problems is solved, but the gradient does not look smooth.

Comment: What do you mean by 1 and 0? Do you want to convert the range between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customization of the scale is made possible by setting the scale value and the numerical value or string for the scale.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

# Spatial axes
dx, dz = 100, 100
x = np.arange(0, 60000, dx)
z = np.arange(0, 30000, dz)

[zz, xx]= np.meshgrid(z, x, indexing='ij')

# Velocity model
vel = 1000 + 0.032 * zz

fig = px.imshow(vel, labels=dict(x="x[km]", y="z[km]", color="Velocity (m/s)"), color_continuous_scale='RdBu')
fig.update_layout(title='Raytrace')

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(0,600,100), ticktext=np.arange(0,60,10))
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=np.arange(0,300,50), ticktext=np.arange(0,30,5))

fig.show()
```

[image]